# KNN ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, nan

here is my code, it's supposed to be a simple regression algorithm. The data set has about 500 samples, each of them have 12 factors. I received this error though:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float64').

Code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('/Users/chrisrivas/Documents/Andrew     Haines/Datasets/GRD.csv', header=None, sep=',')

#coverts dataset into 2d array of values and seperates target column
#[1st to: last rows, and 1st to: 12th columns ]
samples = dataset.loc[:, 1:12].values
targets = dataset[13].values

print(samples)
print(targets)

#training and testing of dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
samples, targets, test_size=0.35, random_state=0)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = knn.predict(X_test)

#calculates accuracy of algorithm    
print("Test set score: {:.2f}%".format(np.mean(y_pred == y_test)*100))

#opens new data for algorithm to make classification predictions 
dataset2 = pd.read_csv('/Users/chrisrivas/Documents/Datasets/GoldRushDataset-41.csv', header=None, sep=',').values

#continues to loop for each sample and their classification prediction
for sample in dataset2:
    prediction = knn.predict([sample])
    print("Prediction: {}".format(prediction))
    print('    ')    

#other format for predictions: all at a time in array
prediction = knn.predict(dataset2)
print("Prediction: {}".format(prediction))
```

Comment: Have you checked for NaNs (*not a number*) in your `dataset2`? eg. with `dataset2.isnull().values.any()`?

Comment: No, but I just tried it and my output didnt have any new information for me...

Comment: What is the output? Does dataset2 have NaNs?

Comment: And another thing: Why don't you treat the samples the same way as you did with the training data? I.e. `knn.predict(dataset2.loc[:, 1:12].values)`

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it to work now, but I'm noticing that every time I run the code I get the same score on the test. I thought it would train and test on random samples every time I run thr code but its not. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you post this as a new question. Please also accept my answer so that other can see that your first question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked for NaNs (not a number) in your dataset2? eg. with `dataset2.isnull().values.any()`?

Another thing that might be the cause of your error: You need to treat the samples the same way as you treat your training data:

```
knn.predict(dataset2.loc[:, 1:12].values)
```